# Unable to modify files directly even after changing permission

Tags: hard-drive, ssd, permission, high-sierra

**Background:**

I have added an additional SSD to my iMac and made it the startup disk. The old 1TB hard disk is still attached and is now the secondary hard drive.

The new drive is formatted to APFS. Old drive is still 'Mac OS extended (journaled)'

**Goal:**

I want to fix the permission of my files on secondary hard drive such that I can easily manipulate my old files

**What I have done:**

I used `Cmd+I` to bring up the Info dialog box, and give `antkong (Me)` the `read & write` permission. Then I used 'apply to the enclosed items...' option to apply the new permission to subfolder and files.

It seems to work for me because the stop badges (minus in a red circle) on subfolders are gone.

[image]

**Problem:**

I tried to delete some files in one of the subfolder. I still get prompted for the sudo password

[image]

I expect that I can manipulate files as if I am the owner.

Why this happens? How can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest method would be to check "Ignore ownership on this volume"

Get Info on the drive itself rather than an individual folder.
You should see the checkbox at the bottom, available once you unlock the admin padlock.

[image]

Comment: I didn't know this feature exists! Thanks for the answer. Unfortunately I really want to retain the permissions because it is a shared PC. I want other users to have read access only.

Comment: Are the other users admins? If so they could just do this for themselves anyway. I'm wondering if adding a group would help your initial setup, rather than just owner & everyone.. [will run some tests...]